# What does setContentLength() method of ServletResponse actually do?

Tags: http, jsp, servlets

According to the documentation, the `setContentLength(int len)` method of the `ServletResponse` interface sets the length of the content body in the response In HTTP servlets, this method sets the HTTP Content-Length header.

- Parameters:
  `len` - an integer specifying the length of the content being returned to the client; sets the Content-Length header

Here is the from the `doGet()` method of the class which extends `HttpServlet`:

```java
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setContentLength(6);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write("What's your name? ");
    out.write("" + response.isCommitted());
}
```

When I run this on the Chrome browser, the output is: **`What's your name? false`**

I am confusing what actually is the metric for calculating the length of the `setContentLength()` here, whether it is in byte, character, or something, and if it sets the content length of the body, why `response.isCommitted()` returns `false` and the length of the text I want to output was not truncated somehow? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am confusing what actually is the metric for calculating the length
> of the setContentLength() here, whether it is in byte, character, or
> something

It's in `byte`.

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) or **Section#14.13 Content-Length** of the [specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)  for details.

> When I run this on the Chrome browser, the output is: **What's your
> name? false**

I doubt the validity of what you are saying.

**Given below is the screenshot of my Chrome browser:**

[image]

**Given below is the screenshot of my Firefox browser:**

[image]